# How does JSF render more than one JSP pages into 1 single view?

Tags: jsp, jsf, binding, frontend

I have an application where the WebContent folder has a number of `.jsp` pages like `navigation.jsp, primarytabs.jsp` etc.

The `navigation.jsp` contains a vertical menu and the `primarytabs.jsp` contains a tab on top, and some other jsps contain individual components.

When I run the application of the application server, it opens up a welcome page, and all these navigation items, and tabs and others merge into a single view and show us a well formed combination of all these components.

I did some studying and read about "composite views". But I wasn't sure if I can call this composite view or not.

Can you please enlighten me about how JSF combines all these jsps into one view and where to find that "binding" within the code so I can make the relevant changes?

Thank you very much.

More details:

Thank you very much for the answers. I have gone through the code and have seen

```
src="<%= request.getContextPath() %> /faces/tabs.jsp 
src="<%= request.getContextPath() %> /faces/navigator.jsp
```

and so on. I presume these perform the similar function that you have described above with the include tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You welcome page might look something like this:

Welcome.jsp:

```
<jsp:include page="/include/header.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="/include/navigation.jsp" />

<!-- Content of Page -->

<jsp:include page="/include/footer.jsp" />
```

Think of Welcome.jsp being a refrigerator and the includes being magnets that are on the page.

If you would like to change something in the `header.jsp` that would change on every page it is included on, templating in a sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have gone through the code and have seen 

src="<%= request.getContextPath() %> /faces/tabs.jsp 
src="<%= request.getContextPath() %> /faces/navigator.jsp

and so on. I presume these perform the similar function that you have described above?

Comment: correct, that request.getContextPath() is the root of your filesystem, the path to the file. @user3641003

Comment: I usually call it templating with composite components. So I guess kinda... :) @user3641003

Comment: if this post solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the answer. @user3641003

Comment: Yes Sir. It did help my task. Thank you very much. It was clear and concise.

Comment: Would you please click the green check mark under the rating for me then? :D Thanks in advance @user3641003

Answer (score 0):

Read about "Apache Tiles", it may give you some clue for your doubt.

And check about

```
 <jsp:include page"XXXXX.jsp" />.
```

It is another way of doing the same.