# JSF Webapp-Template for many Webapp-Projects

Tags: java, jsf, templates, tomcat, web-applications

I'm searching for a hint/solution to generate one Template-Webapp with a custim design and then all my other Webapps should take the design from the Template-Webapp. Is that possible? The Idea behind is, that we I have multiple Webapps for Projects, but the Layout,... is the same on all Project. And when changing the Template-Webapp, all other Webapps are changed without changing the source-code in all Webapps.

I've got a running Webapp with my design(Template-Webapp). All is runing on a Tomcat 7. In another Webapp, I tried to use the template-file from the Template-Webapp, but I can't get it running. Perhaps its not possible to navigate through the webapp-folders on Tomcat? It's showing "invalid path"-failure. But, the path is correct. With selecting the path, I can easy access the template-file.

Does anybody had the same problem or knows how to solve it ?

Thanks for every help, even if it's small

Answer (score 0):

You should look into breaking your front-end pieces up.

It ends up being like moving magnets around on a refrigerator. Except the magnets are components of your template!

It is called templating with composite values.

My Related Answer:

- [How does JSF render more than one JSP pages into 1 single view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679991/how-does-jsf-render-more-than-one-jsp-pages-into-1-single-view/23680701#23680701)

Documentation:

- [JSF 2 fu: Templating and composite components](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html)
- [Core J2EE Patterns - Composite View - Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compositeview-137722.html)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on some webresources how to work with templating (JSF > 2.0) and contracts (JSF > 2.2).

- http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/
- http://hantsy.blogspot.de/2013/08/jsf-22-theme.html

The best way to share one template across many projects is to bundle the contract including all recources into one *.jar

As far as i know, the template/contract/whatever should be in the right directorys, thus within the same project at least included as jar.